# Enforce type of property to sort by in typescript

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I want to sort an array of objects by a numeric property in typerscript.

To do this, I've got the below code. This has the problem that it doesn't enforce that the value at the `prop` key of `T` need be numeric. Of course I could just check this at runtime with checking the type of any of the values in `arr`, but I would like to know how to enforce this at compile time through the use of typescript.

```
function sortByProperty<T>(arr : T[], prop : keyof T) : T[] {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => a[prop] - b[prop]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would look like this:

```
function sortByProperty<T extends Record<K, number>, K extends PropertyKey>(
  arr: T[],
  prop: K & keyof T
): T[] {
  return arr.sort((a, b) => a[prop] - b[prop]);
}
```

We store the type of `prop` in a new generic type `K` and enforce that `T` must be an object type where the type of the property `K` is `number`.

This leads to a compile time error, if we choose a property name which does not correspond to a `number` property.

```
// valid
sortByProperty([{
    a: "",
    b: "",
    c: 0
}], "c")

// Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
sortByProperty([{
    a: "",
    b: "",
    c: 0
}], "a")
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgJygIQJ4AU1wAOAphtgDwAqixAHlMWACbKIBKxE6T5A0gDSIwIALYAjUgD5BvGvUYtE+IqSjZexbJIAUAKESIAhmjQAuRJQDaAXX77EhAoXOyAZIgDWmuMAu6AlOZW1ogA3vZoxFAgaEjGaAB0qBja2oaCYv6IALySRpaORCEAtIhiBU7W-gDcugC+uroA9E2IAG6GADYwTLrJWHhOqtjaluEGBobmAETTdhNlM3P2BhDmAAz1tojTENP+jS2IAKIm6EHYJIgA5MhQaDBgAObXiDCsYHBQRsjIME9gQxiTrERBQOBgy6g67CcSka59dADZQkMijcYTKY7ZYLMRLeYTNaITZ1bbTQz7IA)